# Count the uniquness of a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have this sheet:

[image]

As you can see I am determining the uniqueness of a value by this formula:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A=A2)*($B:$B=B2)*($C:$C=C2))>1;"NOT UNIQUE";"UNIQUE")`

This formula basically checks if the the `identifier` the `value` and the `date` are all three different(unique). If two are the same then its still unique.

However, what I would like to achive is that I want to count its uniqueness, so that I I get:

[image]

As you can see if the `identifier` the `value` and the `date` are coming up more than once than a counter counts +1 if not then it starts at 1 again.

Is this possible with my previous formula?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one in `E2` and drag it down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2,C2)
```

[image]